# How to move an iOS layer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to move my layer, which contains a black dot, to a new position every time the `moveToPosition()` function is called. The `moveToPosition()` function is rapidly called many times with a new position that is calculated each time, so ideally I would see the dot move around in a smooth path. I've tried the following:

```
func moveToPosition(newPosition: CGPoint) {
    print (newPosition.x, newPosition.y, redLayer.position)
    self.redLayer.position = newPosition
}

func moveToPosition(newPosition: CGPoint) {
    print (newPosition.x, newPosition.y, redLayer.position)

    var movement = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "movement")
    movement.fromValue =  NSValue(CGPoint: self.redLayer.position)
    movement.toValue = NSValue(CGPoint: toPoint)
    movement.duration = 0.3

    self.redLayer.addAnimation(movement, forKey: "position")
    self.redLayer.position = toPoint
}
```

From [How can I move an image in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32133056/how-can-i-move-an-image-in-swift), I also tried the code below:

```
func moveToPosition(newPosition: CGPoint) {
    print (newPosition.x, newPosition.y, redLayer.position)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.75, delay: 0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {
        self.redLayer.position = newPosition
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

But perhaps this code did not work since it is meant for a UIView and not a layer?

Anyway, none of these have worked - from my print statement, I see that newPosition.x and newPosition.y change every time, but the dot itself does not move on the screen. Any ideas? I'm very new to iOS so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What kind of object is `redLayer`?

Comment: At what point in your code are you calling moveToPosition?  The Position of a CALayer has an implicit animation so you shouldn't have to create your own CABasicAnimation.  It does not look like your CABasicAnimation is created properly anyway because it is trying to change the `movement` property of `redLayer` and if redLayer is a CA Layer it does not have a `movement` property (it looks like you swapped the `movement` and `position` entries in CABasicAnimation(...) and redLayer.addAnimation

Comment: redLayer is a CALayer().

Comment: I am calling moveToPosition in a delegate method in ViewController.swift. If a CALayer has its own implicit animation, then would the first piece of code that I tried be close to the answer?

Answer (score 2):

A `CALayer` instance is the underlying visual object behind every `UIView` instance in UIKit. When you move or animate a view's layer, it doesn't move the view, but only the visual representation of the view. Once the animation is complete, the layer is updated to reflect the view's actual frame (the model).

To answer your question, to move a view's layer, you can do two things:

1. Change the view frame, which in turn will update the layer. For eg.:

   ```
   UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {

      movingView.frame = updatedFrame;
   }
   ```
2. Update the layer directly (for eg., using CoreAnimation), but at the end, update the view's model to reflect the new position/frame.

[This](http://blog.spacemanlabs.com/2011/08/calayers-parallel-universe/) article, for instance, explains the model/view separation in UIKit.