# Swift 4 Expression type '@value CGRect' is ambiguous without more context

Tags: swift, cgrect

I am trying to implement a animation for a rectangle to perform modal vertical swipe.However, when I try to compile the code I get the following error "Swift 4 Expression type '@value CGRect' is ambiguous without more context". I have isolated the issue to the arguments that is being passed to the CGRect init value, but according the Apple's iOS documentation these parameters should be enough to specify the 'frame' view that I need to animate.

Here is my code:

```
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    guard
        let fromView = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from),
        let toView = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to)

    else {
            return
    }
    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
    containerView.insertSubview((toView.view)!, belowSubview: (fromView.view)!)

    let toFrame = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: toView)

    let screenBounds = UIScreen.main.bounds

    let bottomLeftCorner = CGPoint(x: 0, y: screenBounds.height)

    let finalFrameForVC = CGRect(origin: bottomLeftCorner, size: screenBounds.size)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 1,
                   options: [], (using: transitionContext.finalFrame(for: fromView)),
        animations: {
            fromView.view.frame = finalFrameForVC
    },
        completion: { _ in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
    })
}
```

Comment: This problem belongs to data type, I tried to subtract value between CGFloat and Int types, later I converted both in to same type Ex: **width: Int((filterView?.filterTblView.frame.width)!)-Int(width!)**

Answer (score 43):

I had the same error when I tried to multiply view.frame.height by a Double.  If you are doing any math on screenBounds properties, make sure the types match.

Answer (score 39):

My problem was that I was trying to perform an operation between a **CGFloat** variable and **Double** variable.

**Fix:** Convert the Double variable to **CGFloat**. Check your variable types.

I hope it helps! :)

Comment: This was my problem as well. What a useless error message

Comment: Same as yours... The solution is simply putting your "wrong" variable into CGFloat( HERE ).

Comment: Helping a lot!! In my case I was comparing CGFloat and CGPoint.

Answer (score 15):

I got here looking for an answer to what was causing the error "Expression type '@lvalue CGRect' is ambiguous without more context", and while nothing here answered this for me I did find the solution to the problem so I'll leave it here for anyone else who stumbles on this question via Google. When creating your CGRect make sure to explicitly cast any ambiguous values to CGFloats (e.g. var width = CGFloat(100)) instead of relying on the compiler to infer the correct type/cast for you.

Comment: Or you could set local variable first and than put it to the function as a parameter. Result- no errors. 
let viewWidth = view.bounds.width
let viewHeight = view.bounds.height

scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: viewWidth, height: viewHeight)

Answer (score 9):

This is a bug in XCode 10.1 which I am about to report.

```
let myHeight = CGFloat(100)

myHeight -= myView.frame.height
```

This produces the error:

> "Expression type '@lvalue CGRect' is ambiguous without more context"

The error is wrong, the problem is that `myHeight` is a constant.

Comment: any response from Apple?

Answer (score 5):

For me, I was putting `Int` as CGRect **height**.

Xcode was mistakenly pointing to `y` with this error

> Expression type '@value CGRect' is ambiguous without more context

[image]

### Solution

Just implicitly define the height as `CGFloat`

```
let height:CGFloat = 100
```

Comment: @YogeshPatel, Then voting up would be appropriated ;)

Answer (score 4):

It's not your `finalFrameForVC` which rise the exception "'@value CGRect' is ambiguous without more context" but it's `fromView.view.frame`.

Fix it by declaring `fromView.view` explicitly as UIView :

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 1, options: [], animations: {
      let view: UIView = fromView.view
      view.frame = finalFrameForVC as! CGRect
    }) { _ in
      transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
    }
```

Comment: Yes I know, but the compiler is asking you to specify that it is a UIView. I don't know why :(

Comment: This worked to me, thanks! It is not an uncommon error of Xcode when it says "too complex expression" and you have to break it into meaningful parts.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your animation call which

1. is incorrectly written
2. the method does not exist

Reformatted:

```
UIView.animate(
   withDuration: 2,
   delay: 1,
   options: [],
   (using: transitionContext.finalFrame(for: fromView)),
   animations: {
     fromView.view.frame = finalFrameForVC
   },
   completion: { _ in            
     transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
   }
)
```

Note the `(using: transitionContext.finalFrame(for: fromView)),`. You cannot wrap a part of the method in parentheses including one of the external parameter names, it would have to be:

```
UIView.animate(
   withDuration: 2,
   delay: 1,
   options: [],
   using: transitionContext.finalFrame(for: fromView),
   animations: {
     fromView.view.frame = finalFrameForVC
   },
   completion: { _ in            
     transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
   }
)
```

That is what is causing the error. However, there is also no animation method with `using:` part, therefore I suppose it's just a copy-paste error and you actually want just:

```
UIView.animate(
   withDuration: 2,
   delay: 1,
   options: [],
   animations: {
     fromView.view.frame = finalFrameForVC
   },
   completion: { _ in            
     transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
   }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem just now. and i fix it like this:

[image]

and like the example above that: self.view must be assigned to another variable, ant the view should be force cast: view!, and then compile will work successfully.

Comment: Hi, Please never post a screenshot of your code, simply use the CODE TAGS to post your code.

Answer (score 1):

Really silly n00b answer,I had the same issue

> "Expression type '@lvalue CGRect' is ambiguous without more context"

It was cause because I pressed *return* before `CGFloat`. Check to make sure it's on the same line. Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error when I tried to create a `CGRect` and forgot to add `.constant` to the end of a variable name for an `NSLayoutConstraint`

Answer (score 0):

Like Rory Prior wrote above I got this error trying to make a `CGPoint` and I needed to specify that the parameters were `CGFloat` but I also needed to label the parameters x: and y: going into `CGPoint` so that `CGPoint` knew to expect `CGFloat`. Here's the code:

```
let topRight = CGPoint(x:CGFloat(cellTitleLabel.frame.maxX),y:CGFloat(cellTitleLabel.frame.minY))
```

Answer (score 0):

The example

```
myView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CGFloat(videoImaView.frame.width * CGFloat(0.4)), height: height)
```

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly declare a copy of the variable you want to change then assign it back.

```
func clickButton() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, animations: {
        let buttonFrame = self.button.frame
        buttonFrame.origin.y = buttonFrame.origin.y - 1.0
        self.button.frame = buttonFrame
    }
}
```

credit to Rishi's answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32133196/11683453